# SSIS packages -- running programmatically without SSIS installed on client box

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I've seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx) link about running an SSIS package in a C#/.Net application on someone's box who doesn't have SSIS installed.

I thought I'd ask if since that article has been published if there's another way to allow an end user to run an SSIS package on their box without having SSIS intalled.  I'd hoped that my C# application's reference to the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime assembly would do the trick, but that's just not the case.

It would be easier at my work to have the users install SSIS than try the workaround mentioned in the article, whereby a windows service on a 3rd box does most of the work.  But I thought I'd check if there'd been any breakthroughs on doing this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have SSIS installed on the machine in order to use the API. I do not think you want to do that because Microsoft wants you to have a SQL Server license for every machine that has SSIS installation, even without the SQL Server part. This will get expensive real quick. I think your idea of having an Agent Server that runs the packages on request will work best.

HTH